# Minimum number of characters before hx-get?

Tags: htmx

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a minimum number of characters before the request is dispatched in an input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can filter events in html using a filter expression, and use that to examine the number of characters in the input:

```html
  <input ... hx-trigger="keyup[target.value.length > 10]" ...>
```